# Android webview - passing a callback function

Tags: javascript, webview

I have a javascript interface in my java code for my webview javascript:

```
@JavascriptInterface
public String test(String name, Object Callback) {
    // I would like to execute the callback on the javascript
}
```

I would like to pass it something like this from my webview:

```
MyJavaAPI.test('My Name', function(result) {
    alert(result);
});
```

I searched but could only find people who suggest passing name of function and using loadUrl along with "javascript:NAME_OF_FUNCTION()" - but that is no what I want.

I think what I would like to accomplish is possible because it's been done on platforms like Phonegap - I tried looking at the Phonegap code to learn but couldn't understand how they implemented this.

Am I right? can this be done? how?

Thanks

Comment: from the test I made, you can only pass strings or primitives to JavascriptInterface

Comment: Hi @njzk2 - you have any idea how phonegap implements that? thanks

Comment: one solution would be to create a named function, pass the name of the function, and call it (`loadUrl("javascript:<machin>);`) from the java.

Comment: @njzk2 as mentioned above - this is not the solution I was looking for.

Comment: I'm afraid there aren't much other solutions.

Comment: Did you find any solution??